# how to run tomcat server using with different name instead of localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

Recently i started  doing java programming.My requirement is i have to run my web  application using tomcat server.i want to provide security to my application by giving different name to tomcat server.

I tried options like changing host name in server.xml file,but this option is not working for me.

```
<Host name="dileep"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

Thanks in advance.I am expecting exact response for this.

Comment: That isn't security, and you're asking about DNS.

Answer (score 0):

try Alias like below.

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Alias>www.dileep</Alias></Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may Help You...

```
<Host name="www.myHost.com" ......>
     ......
     <Alias>myHost.com</Alias>
     ......
</Host>
```